# New template from my custom package is not appearing in RStudio

Tags: r, templates, r-markdown, package, devtools

While I can successfully load my custom R package from GitHub, the custom template I created within it is not appearing when I click "New File / R Markdown / From Template".

I have closely followed the steps from these two guides on installing new templates as part of a custom R package:
http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_document_templates.html
http://ismayc.github.io/ecots2k16/template_pkg/

This feels like a difficult problem to trouble shoot so I'll include the code that I used to generate the template.

```
setwd("~/Google Drive/projects")

library(devtools)

create("basictemplate")

dir.create("basictemplate/inst/rmarkdown/templates/report/skeleton",
           recursive = TRUE)
```

Save your template as skeleton.Rmd in the skelton directory.

Create the template.yaml file by doing File -> New File -> Text file.
The first line of the text file reads:
  name: Basic Report
The second line is left blank.

Then save this text file as template.yaml in the skeleton directory with skeleton.Rmd

```
install("basictemplate")
library(basictemplate)
```

And after all that there is no basictemplate to be found when I open a new R Markdown. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some of the documentation seems to suggest that `template.yaml` should be saved in `"basictemplate/inst/rmarkdown/templates/report"`, not the `skeleton/` subdirectory.

Comment: That was precisely the problem @Marius. Thank you for your careful review of my question. I can now load the template.

Comment: I have my `template.yaml` in `"basictemplate/inst/rmarkdown/templates/report"` but still can't see the template in the dialog